# Entity Framework entity referencing another twice

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

I have this Product class for an order taking restaurant application:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServingChoice> ServingChoices { get; set; }
}
```

A product may have a choice of serving, like 'Soup of the Day' offers the user the choice of choosing among a few products.
Both the Product and Choices are both of type `Product`:

```
public class ServingChoice
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ChoiceId { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ServingChoices")]
    public Product Choice { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing something wrong, since a Product never loads its choices. The table seems to be created correctly.

### Edited

It looks like kinda works, but inversed. If I manually ad into the database some records, like this:

```
ProductID | ChoiceID
1           10
2           10
3           10
```

it works for the Product with Id=10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is because you are not mapping the FKs as you should. Try this:

```
public class ServingChoice
{
  //...
  [ForeignKey("Product")]
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Choice")]
  public int ChoiceId { get; set; }

  public Product Product { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("ServingChoices")]
  public Product Choice { get; set; }
 }
```

BTW, you are configuring two one-to-many relationships, but in the relationship where is involve the `Product` navigation property (in the `ServingChoice` class) you are not defining the other end. If you want to do that, you should declare another navigation property in the `Product` entity:

```
public class Product
{
  [Key]
  //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] this is not necessary, it's the default behavior
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<ServingChoice> ProductChoices { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ServingChoice> ServingChoices { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the `ServiceChoice` class you should  add the `InverseProperty` annotation on the `Product` navigation property to specify explicitly what is the other end of the relationship:

```
public class ServingChoice
{
  [Key]
  // [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] the same I explain before
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Product")]
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Choice")]
  public int ChoiceId { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("ProductChoices")]
  public Product Product { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("ServingChoices")]
  public Product Choice { get; set; }
 }
```

Also, you can use **Fluent Api** following the same idea:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<ServingChoice>().HasRequired(m => m.Product).WithMany(m => m.ProductChoices).HasForeignKey(m=>m.ProductId);
     modelBuilder.Entity<ServingChoice>().HasRequired(m => m.Choice).WithMany(m => m.ServingChoices).HasForeignKey(m=>m.ChoiceId);
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know the use of `Product` navigation property in your logic, but you if you like, don't declare the `ProductChoice` property, it's not required. Try just mapping the FKs. Now seeing your model once more  I think that can solve your problem. Try add some elements and tell me what happend after that.

Comment: After setting the Inverse property well, it works. Thanks. But a new problem arrises now: after saving an Order containing a Product, all the ServingChoice items of the product are doubled in the database. Any ideea why?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Order` and `Product` and how are you saving an `Order`?

Comment: `Order has many OrderItems` and `Product` belongs to `OrderItem`. I edited the question to include those classes.

Comment: I think you problem is because you are working with detached entities.If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but which is not currently being tracked by the context then you can tell the context to track the entity using the Attach method on DbSet. The entity will be in the Unchanged state in the context.

Comment: Hello @HMihail, If you think my answer helped you to resolve your initial issue, could you please, mark it as answered.